# Order table by column with checkbox values

Tags: jquery, datatables

I looked on tutorial https://www.datatables.net/examples/plug-ins/dom_sort.html

but there is missing example for the checkbox.
I tried this

```
/* Create an array with the values of all the checkboxes in a column */
$.fn.dataTable.ext.order['dom-checkbox'] = function  ( settings, col )
{
    return this.api().column( col, {order:'index'} ).nodes().map( function ( td, i ) {
        return $('input', td).prop('checked') ? '1' : '0';
    });
}

$('#filterResultTable').DataTable({
            "sDom": "H", // remove header (record count + search textbox)
            "paging": false, // show all records on 'first' page
            "order": [[1, "asc"]], // default order bis by 2nd column,
            "aoColumns": [
                { "orderDataType": "dom-checkbox" },
                null,
                null,
                null,
                null,
                null,
                null
            ]
});
```

but with no luck, no visible error here.
Any idea ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `columns` property instead of `aoColumns` property.